# Electrical outlet acting funny

Tags: electrical, receptacle, circuit-breaker, troubleshooting

My wife and I moved into our new house today. I plugged my phone charger in tonight and the outlet sparked and my breaker tripped. I then plugged a different charger in and it didn't trip. I went to a different outlet (on the same circuit) and plugged the charger I suspected to be faulty in and it worked fine. I'm fairly electrically literate and this has me stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: what kind of a breaker tripped?

Comment: Does the breaker that tripped have a TEST button on it?

Comment: Turn off the breaker, pull out the receptacle and examine the wiring. Possibly there is simply a loose connection . . . or a neutral or ground is close to contacting a hot wire and does so when manipulated. If the current receptacle is "backwired" in the spring loaded contacts, switch the wires to the side contacts.

Comment: The breaker does not have a test button. I'm not sure what kind it is, its 200A breaker box, on a 15A circuit